# comparing two decimal values with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to pop up a message to the user when one value is bigger than the other with javascript. I've used float but when the scripts should show true it doesn't show up

```
appVersionAndroid = '1.9'
appVersionWebAndroid = '1.10'

if(parseFloat(this.appVersionAndroid) < parseFloat(this.appVersionWebAndroid)) {
  alert('needs update')
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your condition is correct?

Comment: This won't work. Instead, split the strings by dot and compare each number in the array, starting from left.

Comment: `appVersionAndroid` is `1.9` which is the same as `1.90`. `appVersionWebAndroid` is `1.10`. `1.90 > 1.10`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're code is ok and there is no issue. There is a small mistake where you put the values. you put the `appVersionAndroid` value "1.9" and `appVersionWebAndroid` value 1.10, here in actually the first value is greater then second because float converter have two decimal number, I means 1.9 means 1.90 here which is greater then 1.10. So thats why your condition go to false.

Sorry for my english. But I think you understand what i want to say.

```js
appVersionAndroid = "1.10"
appVersionWebAndroid = "1.90"
 if(parseFloat(this.appVersionAndroid) < parseFloat(this.appVersionWebAndroid)){
alert('needs update')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`1.9` is bigger than `1.10`. That's why alert doesn't show up.

Answer (score 2):

the number 1.1 (which is the same as 1.10) is not greater that 1.9

You could for instance use 2 different variables for the version before and after the dots.

The main idea is to treat the number before and after the dot as two different integers numbers (for instance you can call them *major* and *minor* version), and it's not at all the same as having a big float number.

Then implement a comparison function which would go like this :

First compare the major number. If it's equal, compare the minor number.